# Astro, seeing `X [ERROR] The build was canceled` in build output (npm run build)

Tags: svelte, astrojs

I'm seeing the following the following error in the console logs on `npm run build` (`"build": "astro check && astro build"`). The build actually completes following this, but I don't like not understanding what's goin on here.

I have included the standard Astro blog template files and the Svelete integration.

I have narrowed the issue down to some sort of conflict between the Svelte integration and the `content/config.ts` file for the blog, because when I take Svelte references out from `astro.config.mjs` out, rollback to a version before the inclusion of blog files or move the `content/config.ts` file, the `X [ERROR] The build was canceled` line goes away.

What's causing this?

I have included the content below of what I think are the relevant files.

`astro.config.mjs`

```
import { defineConfig } from 'astro/config';
import svelte from '@astrojs/svelte';
import mdx from '@astrojs/mdx';
import sitemap from '@astrojs/sitemap';
import tailwind from '@astrojs/tailwind';

// https://astro.build/config
export default defineConfig({
    site: 'https://example.com',
    integrations: [svelte(), tailwind(), mdx(), sitemap()],
});
```

`svelte.config.js`

```
import { vitePreprocess } from '@astrojs/svelte';

export default {
    preprocess: vitePreprocess(),
};
```

`config/blog/config.ts`

```
import { defineCollection, z } from 'astro:content';

const blog = defineCollection({
    // Type-check frontmatter using a schema
    schema: z.object({
        title: z.string(),
        description: z.string(),
        // Transform string to Date object
        pubDate: z.coerce.date(),
        updatedDate: z.coerce.date().optional(),
        heroImage: z.string().optional(),
    }),
});

export const collections = { blog };
```

Comment: Which version of the Svelte integration are you using? May be related to this issue: https://github.com/withastro/astro/pull/9387

Comment: I tried with the stable Svelte version also. 4.2 I believe.

Answer (score 3):

I have the same problem, after several experiments I found out that the problem disappears after deleting the folder "./src/content/"

Unfortunately, this is not a solution to the problem, because it is still necessary to work with the content, but perhaps this information will help find the source of the problem.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I removed the content folder and this message dissapeared. Requesting Astro team to correct error message to "Content Build Failed" Please